# Sum list values where index 0 values match?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a list of lists and I want to merge them to sum the inner `index[1]` values where the `index[0]` values match. My list looks like this:

```
lists = [
['Gifts', [4]],
['Gifts', [4]],
['Politics', [3]],
['Supply', [4]],
['Supply', [4]],
['Prints', [1]],
['Prints', [1]],
['Prints', [1]],
['Politics', [3]],
['Politics', [3]],
['Accounts', [2]],
['Accounts', [2]],
['Accounts', [2]],
['Features', [3]],
['Features', [2]]
]
```

I would therefore like the new structure to be:

```
new_lists = [
['Gifts', 8], ['Politics', 9], ['Supply', 8], ['Prints', 3], ['Accounts', 6], ['Features', 5]
]
```

How do I achieve this in Python?

Comment: Are you sure your nesting is correct? Is it `['Gifts', [4]],` or `['Gifts', 4],`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`defaultdict(int)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) from `collections` module:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> for key, value in lists:
...     d[key] += value[0]
... 
>>> dict(d)
{'Gifts': 8, 'Prints': 3, 'Accounts': 6, 'Features': 5, 'Supply': 8, 'Politics': 9}
>>> list(d.items())
[('Prints', 3), ('Features', 5), ('Supply', 8), ('Gifts', 8), ('Accounts', 6), ('Politics', 9)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Or, use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html). You can initialize it either manually by incrementing the values for every key:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter()
for i, j in lists:
    c[i] += l[j]
```

Or, by providing a flat list of the expanded contents, `Counter` will then do the counting for you:

```
c = Counter(sum([[i] * j[0] for i,j in lists], []))
```

In both cases, create the result list by using a list comprehension grabbing the contents of the counter with `c.items()`:

```
r = [[i, j] for i, j in c.items()]
```

Result being:

```
print(r) 
[['Supply', 8], ['Features', 5], ['Prints', 3],
 ['Gifts', 8], ['Accounts', 6], ['Politics', 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `defaultdict`:

```
In [52]: from collections import defaultdict

In [53]: d = defaultdict(int)

In [54]: for name, (val,) in lists:
   ....:     d[name] += val
   ....:     

In [55]: d.items()
Out[55]: dict_items([('Politics', 9), ('Supply', 8), ('Prints', 3), ('Features', 5), ('Gifts', 8), ('Accounts', 6)])
```